# MacBook Pro 2019 playing sound while updating to 10.14.6

Tags: macos, audio, mojave, software-update, web-browser

On my new MacBook Pro 2019, while updating to 10.14.6, sound started playing before the update was even finished. It was autoplay from a tab I had on Chrome before updating. It continued playing until I unlocked it and closed the tab.

Is this behavior normal? How can I avoid this? Has anyone encountered something similar?

Comment: Can you clarify why this seemed strange? I mean, a tab in Chrome that's autoplaying content really has nothing to do with a macOS update, so...? Obviously I'm missing something, so this may clarify for others as well.

Comment: The computer restarted and it was installing the updates (Black screen, X minutes remaining) while Chrome started autoplaying. It wasn't unlocked. @Monomeeth

Comment: Ok, so does that mean you had the black screen showing the whole time and only after it was gone and the update finished you were able to log in, select Chrome and close the tab to stop the audio playing?

Comment: @Monomeeth The audio started playing on the last minutes of the black screen. And yes, as you said, only after the update was finished I was able to log in, close the tab and stop playing.

Answer (score 3):

You’re not crazy. The same exact thing just happened to me updating to 10.15.6. I thought I was going crazy. I was able to stop the Chrome tab playing audio with the pause button on the Touch Bar.

That was the most buck wild thing I’ve ever seen a mac laptop do while updating the OS.